# Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to implement simple ajax GET request . In the callback portion i want to call some function . The code is as below

```
$.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo SITE_URL?>ajax_pages/ajx_getcard.php?id="+obj.value,
          context: document.body
        }).done(function() { 
          $(this).addClass("done");
        });
```

But it is showing exception

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'done' replace_entry.php:105
getCardno replace_entry.php:105
onblur replace_entry.php:118

I am using google chrome

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of jQuery - new versions return a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, that does have `done`.
You can quickly check your version by looking at the source, or typing `$().jquery` into your console.

If you cannot upgrade, the downgraded code should be:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "...",
      context: document.body,
      complete: function() { 
           $(this).addClass("done");
      });
```

Comment: Complete, success & error are getting deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @SandeepGB - Not when you are using an old version of jQuery. I did say "If you cannot upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

Replace the done with success..??

```
$.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo SITE_URL?>ajax_pages/ajx_getcard.php?id="+obj.value,
      context: document.body
    }).success(function() { 
      $(this).addClass("done");
    });
```

Comment: That still won't work on older versions of Jquery - Need to change the syntax slightly: 
`$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'some_script.php',
                data: { "id": Id, "description": description },
                success: function()
                {
                        alert("done!");
                }
        });
`