# PHP: Unable to get the json output into my javascript page as a variable value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have to get output in this format 
  `var sampleTags = ['c++', 'scala'];`

My javascript function is:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){  
             var sampleTags;

            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url('ajax_get_tags/gettags'); ?>"
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                   sampleTags = data;
                }
            });
       ......................
        .......................



 $(function(){  
     var sampleTags = <?php echo json_encode($query) ?>;
```

My php controller is

```
   function gettags(){
    $json_array=$this->tagsmodel->get_all_tags(); 
   echo json_encode($json_array); 
 }
```

My model is

```
 //-------------------------------Function get all tags--------------------------------
function get_all_tags() { 
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->limit('10');
    $this->db->select('tags_name');
    $res = $this->db->get('tags');
    $ret = array();

    foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
          $ret[] = $row['tags_name'];
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

How can get the json output from ajax request to be display its value for a javascript variable? 
 Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: what errors are you getting? (try checking the javascript error log)

Comment: @Blazemonger Actually its this is not duplicate, both are a diffrent question

Comment: @sgroves This error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'`

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what your new question is. "So according to you what should i do to get the correct data format as i explain it above?" is not something any of us can answer. It looks to me you should ask this as a comment on your previous question.

Comment: are you using an older version of jquery? try `success` instead of `done`.

Comment: yeah may be this can be jquery 1.4 . I am trying...

Comment: realize that all i did was look up the `.ajax` function in the jquery help docs and try to figure out what's going on. you could do the same and not have to ask a question at all. googling that error message also gives tons of results. take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363625/object-xmlhttprequest-has-no-method-done it looks like you want to add a key to your request object called `complete` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger  `How can get the json output from ajax request to be display its value for a javascript variable?` I updated my question

Comment: @sgroves still problem  i am having on this ajax request . In my last question i could not get any correct answer for the ajax request. that's why i asked it again..

Comment: that doesn't mean you can't google the error message you got. that's much easier than waiting for someone to answer. BTW the answers you got would be correct if you were using a current version of jquery.

Comment: @sgroves still erro Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'success'

Comment: i updated one of my previous comments. reload the page and read it; it should help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of jQuery, so `.done` won't work. It looks like you want to add a key to your request object called `complete`, with the anonymous function as its value:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url('ajax_get_tags/gettags'); ?>",
  complete: function(data) {
      if (data) {
          sampleTags = data;
      }
  }
});
```

I found this out by googling your error message. One of the results was this question: [Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363625/object-xmlhttprequest-has-no-method-done). You could have just googled the error message and figured this out yourself.

Comment: Now i am using updated version `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`  . Yeah i got that lesson `You could have just googled the error message and figured this out yourself.`

Comment: Sorry sgroves, still it is not populating the values.  I checked console . i found no error  .

Comment: you'll have to do some debugging then. this site isn't for others to do your debugging for you.

Comment: debugging like what? I think there is an error in the ajax funcion. Because i checked the php function is returning values

Comment: using `console.log` or `alert` to check the `data` variable in your JS function would be a good start. beyond that, it's up to you. no one on this site is going to teach you how to debug a program.

Comment: In your sample code, you aren't doing anything with the data other than setting equal to a variable.  You need to do more than that with it to get things to change on the page.

Comment: @Schleis No problem, i figured out my problem

Answer (score -1):

I would like to give a few suggestions

1. Check for the return value form the server side by printing it with die or exit.
2. check the http response in firebug net tab.
   3.

Comment: Well, if you're averse to 'hard work' you should probably give up on programming and go get a job working for the government or something. Sounds like you may be confused about the json you're getting back from your controller. Did you see this? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/